# How to get the values on nested variables in ansible

Tags: json, ansible, yaml

I am trying to fetch the values of the alerts one by one from the file below, to perform certain operations. Is there a way in ansible to do so?

```
        apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
        kind: PrometheusRule
        metadata:
          labels:
            prometheus: k8s
            role: alert-rules
            app: prometheus-operator
            release: prometheus-operator
          annotations:
            exclude.release.openshift.io/internal-openshift-hosted: "true"
          creationTimestamp: "2020-04-22T09:22:14Z"
          generation: 1
          name: free-memory-percentage
          namespace: openshift-monitoring
          selfLink: /apis/monitoring.coreos.com/v1/namespaces/openshift-cloud-credential-operator/prometheusrules/cloud-credential-operator-alerts
        spec:
          groups:
          - name: free-memory
            rules:
            - alert: node_mem_free_Percentage
              annotations:
                description: Node memory is under pressure
              expr: 100 - (100 * node_memory_MemFree_bytes / node_memory_MemTotal_bytes) < 50
              for: 2m
          - name: High-CPU-Usage
            rules:
            - alert: HighCPUUsage4test
              annotations:
                description: CPU usage is above the 0% threshold
              expr: (100 - (avg by (instance) (irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[5m])) * 100)) > 0
              for: 2m
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I would hardcode the alerts in an array and store it in a all.yml file and then use the array. However, I am now required to directly fetch the values from the file and perform operations in a task file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"Fetch the values of the alerts one by one from the file."*

A: Use [json_query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter). Given the `file.yml` with the variables, the tasks below

```yaml
    - include_vars:
        file: file.yml
        name: my_data
    - set_fact:
        my_alerts: "{{ my_data.spec.groups|json_query('[].rules[].alert') }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_alerts
```

give

```yaml
  my_alerts:
  - node_mem_free_Percentage
  - HighCPUUsage4test
```